# Advanced Filter criteria does not work for more than one criterion

Tags: excel, filter, excel-2003

I am trying to filter a column in Excel (2003). The column is populated with "filenames". I want to filter certain types of files using Excel's "Advanced Filters". 
The filename column (B) exists in sheet1, and the filter list in sheet2 column B.

```
  sheet1                sheet2
  column B              column B
1 Heading             1 Heading
2 file.doc            2 <>*.doc
3 file.html           3 <>*.pdf
4 file.pdf            4 <>*.mp3
5 ...                 5 ...
```

This is what I have [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522647/how-to-filter-for-multiple-criteria-in-excel) after many hours of search on the Internet. The problem is that this works for one entry, but not all. I.e. if I mark the entire column B in sheet1 and use column B1:B2 in sheet2 as the area criteria then Excel filters out all files that end with ".doc". But if I use column B1:B4 in sheet2 then nothing happens.

What I have tried so far:

- "<>*.ext"
- ="<>*.ext"
- OR(*.ext,*.ext2)
- OR("*.ext","*.ext2")
- =OR(...)
- <>(...)
- ISERROR(SEARCH())
- and many many more...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is an **OR filter**, you need to put the criteria in the same row. It should look like the following:

```
  Sheet2
  Column B  Column C
1 Heading   Heading
2 <>*.doc   <>*.pdf
```

Here's an excellent post on advanced filters: http://searchengineland.com/advanced-filters-excels-amazing-alternative-to-regex-143680.

Comment: *OR* should be in *different* rows, per the source you gave (and my own experience) : https://morespeech.tinytake.com/sf/MzE0MTkzXzE4NjIzMjk

Answer (score 1):

"AutoFilter allows you to filter using a maximum of two criteria." and "When you want to specify an AND operation you must place the conditions in separate columns." both from [bettersolutions.com](http://www.bettersolutions.com/excel/EDZ483/QT419412321.htm).

I think the best that can be managed this way is to choose two of your sheet2 selections in adjacent columns (say B2 & C2) of sheet2 and then use the range `sheet2!$B$1:$C$2` as the criteria.

Maybe though to get what you want use a PivotTable just of sheet1 ColumnB and filter there.

Comment: Thanks! You're right, but I find it confusing that it has to be an "and" and not an "or" though... I mean: check column x row y if it has A OR B then true|false COMPARE WITH check column x row y if it has A AND B then true|false ??? Btw I choosed Bens answer 'cause I think the visual answer could be easier for Excel-noobs like me :)