# Excel Advance Filter not working

Tags: excel, filter

I have a sheet in which there is a column which mentions some tags.Now i am try to follow the advance filtering to see the data for 2 or 3 tags only but it's not working for me.

I have create a sample excel sheet in which i have taken S.no and Name. In that sheet I am able to apply the filter.I am not able to understand why it's not working in my sheet.

[image]

As per the snapshot i want to filter data for 2 tags `<NbOfTxs> <CreDtTm>`.Please check if anybody can help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Advanced filter in Excel has the hidden ability of regex (regular expression).
Your data just happened to have some special characters used in regex, i.e "<"
So when you want to filter for <NbOfTxs>, I think Advanced Filter will interpret this as "return all entries that larger than <NbOfTxs> meaning anything would come after <NbOfTxs> in the dictionary, for example: <Pst>, <NcOfTxs>, etc.

I don't know the reasons why you want to use Advanced Filter but maybe you can do normal filter or pivot if it still helps achieve your ultimate goal.

Similar question here: 
[Advanced Filter criteria does not work for more than one criterion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975369/advanced-filter-criteria-does-not-work-for-more-than-one-criterion)

You can read more on this feature of Advanced Filter here (from above question):
http://searchengineland.com/advanced-filters-excels-amazing-alternative-to-regex-143680

Comment: The only thing that i want to try that because in normal filter i have to scroll through and select the criterion one by one.