# How do I get the rows having particular number which is separated by ; in same colomn

Tags: excel, wildcard

I used custom filter.This contain 8 but I'm getting all rows having the 8,

> I also used some wildcard character but that didn't work out

please provide me a solution on this

```
--------------------------------------------------
| RuleId  |coverage                 |    Title 
--------------------------------------------------
| 8        | scond row              |
--------------------------------------------------
| 8;14    |  scond row              |
--------------------------------------------------
|18;8     |   scond row             |           
--------------------------------------------------
|8        |    scond row            |
--------------------------------------------------
|7        |  scond row              |
--------------------------------------------------
|9        |  scond row             |
--------------------------------------------------
| 77;178  |      Second row        |
--------------------------------------------------

required Output:-
--------------------------------------------------
| RuleId  |coverage                 |    Title 
--------------------------------------------------
| 8       |  scond row              |
--------------------------------------------------
| 8;14    |  scond row              |
--------------------------------------------------
|18;8     |   scond row             |           
--------------------------------------------------
|8        |    scond row            |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: could you please clarify about how you used the wildcards and what is not working?

Comment: I have used the wildcards like ?,* ,like 8? or 8*  in custom filter but they are not fetching the output I required.

Comment: what output do you require?

Comment: I required all rows which having 8 or 8;14 but not  77;178

Comment: You will need to make use of the `Advanced Filter option` with 4 criteria: (1) `8`, OR (2) `8;*`, OR (3) `*;8`, OR `*;8;*`. Here is a rather good website how to setup such an advanced filter: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/how-to-use-and-and-or-operators-with-excels-advanced-filter/ and here is a similar Q&A on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522647/how-to-filter-for-multiple-criteria-in-excel

Comment: Thanks  Ralph Its working for me :)